# Как найти все возможные суммы непрерывных подмассивов быстрее чем за O(n^2)?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Меня интересует вопрос, как можно достать все возможные суммы подмассива?
Не обязательно его запоминать,а просто вывести сумму.
Я знаю как зделать ето двойным циклом,но есть ли способ ето пощитать одним,или даже с помощью математики? 
Подтолкните пожалуйста на истину,или все-таки скажите что ето нереально.

Comment: Что-то ничего лучше квадрата не придумывается. Если предположить, что все суммы могут быть уникальны, то ответ нельзя. Осталось придумать, как построить такой массив, у которого все суммы уникальны.

Comment: Озадачили. То есть сумму отрезка массива за константное время уже умеете считать ? С использованием вспомогательного массива сумм. То есть у вас точно O(n^2) а не O(n^3) ??

Comment: @vegorov, есть и другие варианты получения квадратичной асимптотики.

Comment: А если использовать префикс масив,и тогда бинарным поиском щитать?

Comment: Если размер выхода алгоритма кватратично зависит от размера входа, то никакого алгоритма, лучшего чем квадратичный, не может существовать по определению.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Берём массив [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...] - сумма любых его элементов уникальна (по сути каждый элемент представляет собой один бит - если его взяли, то 1, если нет, то 0). Сколько у него непрерывных подмассивов? O(n<sup>2</sup>). Получается, что чтобы получить все суммы, надо затратить квадратичное число операций. Видимо, на этом всё - быстрее никак не получится.

Comment: Понятно,все таки нельзя)

Comment: Как-то запутанно написано, массив степеней двойки ничего тут не дает. Проще описать так: мы можем n способами выбрать начало подмассива в массиве и n способами (в худшем случае) выбрать длину подмассива, итого O(n·n) = O(n²)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, и кто сказал, что все суммы будут разными? А если нет, то можно быстрее найти.

Comment: Нас интересует самый худший случай, не так ли?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, всё равно надо доказать, что в худшем случае суммы различны. Вот я и привёл пример такого массива.

Comment: Стоп, а нам нужно ведь не просто перебрать всевозможные подмассивы в заданном массиве, а для каждого проверить дает ли он новую уникальную сумму или нет. Не добавит ли это еще сложности? Т.е. нам надо хранить все уже найденные суммы на каждой итерации проверять есть ли уже такая сумма или нет. Похоже, что минимум уже O(n²·log(n)) получается

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я могу сделать вот так: set с суммами, в котором лежит нулевой элемент и маркер, что он свежий. Теперь для каждого элемента я добавляю в сет суммы всех подотрезков, которые заканчиваются на нём. Для этого я прохожу по сету и если встречаю элемент, помеченный свежим, меняю ему маркер и добавляю как свежий его сумму с текущим (если такая сумма уже есть, то обновляю маркер). Видимо, надо маркер реализовывать как правый индекс. Итого получается O(n\*m\*log(m)), где m - число сумм. Или даже O(n*m), если сет основан на хэшах, а не на на сортировке. Или меньше - оценка довольно грубая.

Answer (score 2):

Если алгоритм должен дать на выходе `O(n^2)` данных (как у вашем случае), то значит минимально возможная сложность будет так же `O(n^2)`.

Вы не сможете заполнить массив размером `n * n` за `O(n log n)` или за `O(n)`.

Comment: Ты никак не доказал, что данных на выходе O(n^2).